# Arduino Wifi Shield SPI commands

Tags: arduino, avr, spi

I'm currently using the [Arduino Wifi Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield). It works fine with the Arduino Library, but I have a project in which I need to get rid of all the Arduino library, and use only the AVR-libc.

Therefore, in order to use the Wifi shield, I would like to know where there is a documentation about the protocol used on the SPI bus between the arduino and the shield, so that I do not need to use the Wifi Library.

Am I forced to look at the source code, or does any document exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for SPI will be contained in the datasheet for the MCU used in the Arduino. For AVR-based Arduinos, look in the section titled "SPI – Serial Peripheral Interface". For the Arduino Due, see the "Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) Programmer Datasheet" section.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I pointed the protocol used by the Wifi shield on top of the SPI bus, as how do you format the message to send an AT command ?